# How to assign a value to the first index of an empty slice in Golang?

Tags: go

I wrote this code but I have panic runtime problem:

```golang
func climbingLeaderboard(scores, alice []int32) []int32 {
  var rank, rankalice []int32
  rank[0] = 1
}
```

Can you tell me where the problem is?

Thank you in advance

Comment: How can I add rank[0]=1?

Comment: `rank` is an empty slice. Use `append` to add elements to it, or `make` to create a slice with nonzero size.

Comment: I used append but it didnt work

Comment: rank=append(rank,1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rank` is an empty slice. 
Using `append` you can add an element

```
var rank []int32        // Create empty slice
rank = append(rank, 1)
```

Or

Using `make` creates a slice of a specific length and access `rank[0]` to set value.

```
rank := make([]int32, 5)  // Create slice of length 5
rank[0] = 1
```

Demo code in the playground [here](https://play.golang.org/p/pZSU6Li-PoT)

Comment: In your spare time try to read here https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

After creating a slice you need to use `append()` to add an element to it:

```
func climbingLeaderboard(scores []int32, alice []int32) []int32 {
   var rank []int32 = []int32{}
   rank = append(rank, 1) // rank[0]  is  1
}
```

Comment: panic: runtime error: index out of range [1] with length 1

Comment: var rank []int32 = []int32{}
rank = append(rank, 1)

Comment: try this one  fy